# Java spring date @Pattern allow empty string in DTO

Tags: java, spring

im working on java web project and i want to validate my DTO date field. i used the @Pattern annotation from `import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;` and this is my code :

```
 @Pattern(regexp = "^([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})$", message = "Date format should be dd/mm/yyyy")
  private String myDatefield;
```

this validationworks fine when i send invalid date format. but the issue is that field is not mandatory so i want to tolerate the case when the field is empty :

```
{
  "myDatefield":""
}
```

but in this cas i still getting the error `"Date format should be dd/mm/yyyy"`

do you have an suggestion how i can modify my regx Pattern to validate date format and accept the empty string.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `^$` should do the trick.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^$|^([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})$", message = "Date format should be dd/mm/yyyy")
  private String myDatefield;
```

- `^$` provides you the case for an empty string
- `|` is the `or` delimiter for alternative patterns